# Nutch No job jar file set

Tags: java, hadoop, nutch, jobs

I messed up my environment somehow and am getting this in hadoop.log

```
mapred.JobClient - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String)
```

I've seen it referenced all over, but haven't found a solution.   I'm running nutch 1.5 on a Mac.

It's maddening because this just started happening after more than 18 months!  I'd very much appreciate someone smarter than me telling me what I've done and how to fix it.